# Add a prefix to generated links, but not to incoming routes

Tags: ruby, routes, portal

Our Rails 4 application needs to be accessible over an archaic portal. This portal works by adding (from the perspective of the browser) a prefix to each URL; this prefix is removed by the portal before forwarding the request to my application.

So the browser calls `https://portal.company.com/portal/prefix/xyzzy/myapp/mymodel/new`; the portal does its thing and requests `https://myserver.company.com/myapp/mymodel/new` (passing along the stripped prefix in some irrelevant way). The prefix is dynamic and can change between requests.

The problem is that the portal is not able to rewrite the HTML pages served by my application. That is, it does not put in the prefix. It expects applications to either only emit relative URLs, or to add the portal prefix themselves.

So:

- A regular URL `/myapp/mymodel/new`, for example, must stay as is for when the application is accessed directly (for certain users which do not use the portal).
- When accessed over the portal, our application must still understand `/myapp/mymodel/new` as usual, but when using `mymodel_new_path` or `link_to @mymodel` or `form_for @my_model` or whatever other magic URL generators there are, it has to add the portal prefix. So, any URL emitted by the application must look like `/portal/prefix/xyzzy/myapp/mymodel/new` where the per-request string `/portal/prefix/xyzzy` is given by some method defined by us (and the part `xyzzy` can change between requests).

How can I achieve that? My `routes.rb` looks like this today:

```
MyApp::application.routes.draw do
  scope ' /myapp' do
    get ...
```

This probably has to stay as is, because URLs in incoming requests do not change when coming from the portal. But how do I influence the outgoing URLs?

Comment: you can write simple middleware to append prefix to all relative paths if the request came from the portal

Comment: @ArkadiuszOleksy, you mean it would do something along the lines of `html.gsub!(/myurlroot/, "portalprefix/myurlroot`? Yes, I had that idea, it should be simple enough, but was kind of hoping to solve the problem at the root of the issue without such rewriting. I'll keep it in mind if nothing else comes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This suggestion will allow you to easily prefix the urls produced by the Rails path helpers as your require. Do note, however, it will also make these extended paths valid requests for your application - they shoud  just route where expected but you'll get get some extra values in the `params` hash that you can ignore, so I suspect this is possibly acceptable.

---

First, add all the prefix bits as optional parameters to your routes' base scope:

```
scope '(:portal/)(:prefixA/)(:prefixB)/myapp' do
  # routes
end
```

Note that the those optional params cannot include the `/` char without it being escaped by the path helpers, so if you have a few levels in the prefix (which it appears you do in the question) you'll need a few different params, all but the last followed by a slash, as above.

With that done, you should define `default_url_options` in your `ApplicationController`, it should return a hash of the values you need in your routes:

```
def default_url_options(_options={})
  {
    portal:  'portal',
    prefixA: 'whatevertheprefixis',
    prefixB: 'nextbitoftheprefix'
  }
end
```

And that should do it, path helpers (along with `link_to @object` etc) should all now include those values every time you use them.

Note that since the `portal` bit at the start is also an optional parameter, you can simply add additional logic to `default_url_options` and have it return an empty hash whenever you do not want this prefixing behaviour.

Comment: This sounds great! I'll try it and get back to you. The additional routes should not be a problem. That aside: how did you find out about this? Is this documented somewhere? I can certainly not see that behaviour in the documentation of `default_url_options`, nor did I even find `default_url_options` mentioned close to `url_for` in the API doc...

Comment: This is something I've done in our own software (we need an ID number injected into the start of most URLs for internal users). The optional params in the routes are just... optional params in routes, nothing special there. But I can't remember how I found `default_url_options` - it wasn't recent - I suspect I was trying to do some ugly patching of the path helpers to make the optional param work and stumbled across it.